# How to save the CRUD operations on a dynamic table to the database?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I am doing project about restaurant automation system and this table about products of restaurant. I am using mvc5 and mssql.

Here is table on my Index View:

```
@model Starset.Models.ViewModel.MixModel2
  <table class="table table-hover mb-0">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Ad</th>
              <th>Fiyat</th>
              <th>KDV</th>
              <th></th>
              <th></th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
          @foreach (var item2 in Model.urunobj)
          {
              <tr>
                  <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.urun_ad)</td>
                  <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.urun_fiyat)</td>
                  <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item2.urun_kdv)</td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td class="td-actions">
                      <a href="#"><i class="la la-edit edit"></i></a>
                      <a href="#"><i class="la la-close delete"></i></a>
                  </td>
              </tr>
          }
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

MixModel2 and urun model:

```
public class MixModel2
{
    public IEnumerable<kategori> katobj { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<urun> urunobj { get; set; }

    public siparis sipobj { get; set; }

}

public partial class urun
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public urun()
    {
        this.siparis = new HashSet<siparis>();
    }

    public int urun_id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> kategori_id { get; set; }
    public string urun_ad { get; set; }
    public string urun_fiyat { get; set; }
    public string urun_kdv { get; set; }

    public virtual kategori kategori { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<siparis> siparis { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class UrunController : Controller
{
    private tdgEntitiess db = new tdgEntitiess();

    // GET: Urun
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var mixmodel2 = new MixModel2
        {
            katobj = db.kategori.Include(p => p.urun).ToList(),
            urunobj = db.urun.Include(a => a.kategori).ToList(),
        };

        ViewBag.tab = "tab";

        return View(mixmodel2);
    }
}
```

I was adding product(urun) with modal so used renderaction for modal body.

Here my question:

How do I dynamically edit-delete the rows of the table in "View" and update it to the database with a save button?

or

Should I do this with json ? I mean get all tables data one var and update to database to normally ?

Comment: I believe you may be looking for an `AJAX` call

Comment: Can you explain more please ?

Comment: I actually want to do it literally like  this comment's edit and delete buttons :D and I know ajax call its for post json obj right

Comment: You can use `AJAX` to make a request to the server (or send data to the server) without reloading the page. More [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want  update, delete rows in a table..Just follow the link below.That will resolve your problem.
[https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/MVC-jQuery-CRUD-Select-Insert-Edit-Update-and-Delete-using-jQuery-AJAX-and-JSON-in-ASPNet-MVC.aspx][1]